# Combining forall and ^^^ in specs2 matchers

Tags: scala, specs2

In Specs2, the `forall` and `foreach` methods can be used to convert a matcher for a single item into a matcher on a sequence of items of the original type, and ^^^ can be used to preprocess the actual *and* expected values before matching them. But how can I combine the two?

I've tried

```
((s must myMatcher(x)) ^^^ (_.toLowerCase)).forall(collection)
```

but that doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem actually has nothing to do with `forall`. After moving the `forall` to the front to increase readability (which isn't necessary), the code can be made to compile by rewriting it as follows:

```
forall(collection) ((_: String) must myMatcher(x) ^^^ (_.toLowerCase))
```

and this can be worked out by reading the specs2 documentation in the section headed "With sequences", and looking at the types involved.

Also, the matcher needs to be a subclass of `org.specs2.matcher.AdaptableMatcher`. If you're writing your own matcher you'll need to manually subclass this class yourself, because specs2 can't know what your matcher is doing and magically adapt it automatically. An example of a class subclassing `AdaptableMatcher` is `org.specs2.matcher.BeTypedEqualTo`.

In the particular case of

```
myMatcher(x) ^^^ (_.toLowerCase)
```

this fragment can be shortened and made more readable and declarative by replacing it with:

```
(myMatcher(x) ignoreCase)
```

if `myMatcher(x)` has type `AdaptableMatcher[Any]` and converts its values to compare to strings.